# Converting strings into floats, int and strings in Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I've to call an API that sometimes returns me numerical values in string format, `"288"` instead of `288`, or `"0.1523"` instead of `0.1513`. Some other times, I get the proper numerical value, `39`. I also get strings like `"HELLO"`.

I need a function that converts all the inputs in its proper format. This means:

- If I get `"288"` convert it to an integer: `288`.
- If I get `"0.323"` convert it to a float: `0.323`.
- If I get `288` leave it as it is (its an integer already).
- If I get `0.323` leave as it is (its a float already).
- If I get `"HELLO"` leave as it is.

This is my try. The thing is that this also converts me all the floats into integers, and I don't want this. This also doesn't work when the string is a string itself (`"HELLO"`). Can someone give me hand?

```
def parse_value(value):
    try:
       value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            value = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return value
```

Comment: I think that _does_ work on `"HELLO"`. You don't need to do anything if the input isn't a string, just return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `isinstance()`:

```
def parse_value(value):
    if isinstance(value, str): # Check if the value is a string or not
        if value.isnumeric(): # Checks if the value is an integer(in the form of a string)
            return int(value)# Returns int of value
        else:
            try:
                return float(value) # Returns the float of that value
            except ValueError: # Incase it's not a float return string
                pass
    return value # return the value as it is if it's not a string.
```

Output:

```
parse_value('12.5')
12.5
parse_value('12')
12
parse_value('hello')
'hello'
parse_value(12)
12
parse_value(12.5)
12.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something quick-and-dirty, just try to convert to `int` or `float` (in that order), if all else fails, just return what you had. Make sure to return early if you don't have a string (so then it is `int` or `float` already) to avoid converting numeric types.

```
def parse(x):
    if not isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    for klass in int, float:
        try:
            return klass(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return x
```

Comment: I'd probably `return klass(x)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, good suggestion, you can then remove the ugly `else: break`

Answer (score -1):

Check if `value` contains a `.`, if it does try converting it to a float, otherwise try converting it to an int, if neither works just return the value.

Comment: This wont work if the string contains a `.`

Comment: Yes. For example the value is `https://google.com`, it checks if it contains a `.`, which it does, so it tries converting it to a float, which'll fail, so it just returns the value, which'll still be a string because it couldn't be converted to a float.

Answer (score -1):

I think `ast.literal_eval` is the right option here

```
from ast import literal_eval

def eval_api(val):
    try:
        return literal_eval(val)
     except NameErrpr:
        Return val
```

Comment: if you pass `'Four'` to `ast.literal_eval` it will definitely raise an error, it would if you passed it to regular `eval` as well, a `NameError`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh yeah, im doing this while in the metro, does this work? If not feel free to edit